# Alternating rows with different values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is a table named `Profile`

```
AutoId     | GroupId | ProfileId   | ProfileName
-------------------------------------------------   
239        |    54   | abcd        |  name1
251        |    44   | efgh        |  name2 
255        |    54   | ijkl        |  name3
256        |    54   | mnop        |  name4
237        |    44   | qrst        |  name5
```

And below is a table named `Group`

```
GroupId    | IsLive 
--------------------
44         |  1
54         |  0
```

I want to show on top those records whose `IsLive` is one and then the below records will be alternating between a record of `IsLive` 1 and 0. For eg.

```
AutoId     | GroupId | ProfileId   | ProfileName    
--------------------------------------------------
237        |    44   | qrst        |  name5
251        |    44   | efgh        |  name2 
255        |    54   | ijkl        |  name3
237        |    44   | qrst        |  name5
239        |    54   | abcd        |  name1
251        |    44   | efgh        |  name2 
256        |    54   | mnop        |  name4
237        |    44   | qrst        |  name5
```

The records of `IsLive` = 1 should get repeated if it is more than `IsLive` = 0. So far my query has been

```
select AutoId, GroupId, ProfileId, ProfileName
from Profile
where GroupId in (select GroupId from Group where isnull(IsLive,0) = 1)
union all
select AutoId, GroupId, ProfileId, ProfileName
from Profile
where GroupId in (select GroupId from Group where isnull(IsLive,0) <> 1)
```

The above query gives me `IsLive` = 1 on top but I am not able to get the alternating rows. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Why is ID 237 repeated 3 times, but 251 only twice even though they are in the same Group?

Comment: because the number of records are limited in the above example result set. if I increase the data, after the 237 Id, a IsLive = 0 record will come and then the 251 Id record will come after it, modified the result set to make it clear for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the question the resultset should have of 8 rows, in that case this query

```
WITH LiveRows AS (
  SELECT p.AutoID, p.GroupId, p.ProfileID, p.ProfileName
       , ID = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY p.AutoId) - 1
       , Rows = COUNT(1) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL)
  FROM   [Profile] p
         INNER JOIN [Group] g ON p.GroupId = g.GroupId
  WHERE  g.IsLive = 1
), DeadRows AS (
  SELECT p.AutoID, p.GroupId, p.ProfileID, p.ProfileName
       , ID = Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY p.AutoId) - 1
  FROM   [Profile] p
         INNER JOIN [Group] g ON p.GroupId = g.GroupId
  WHERE  g.IsLive = 0
), Ordered As (
SELECT d.AutoID
     , ID = l.Rows + d.ID * 2
FROM   DeadRows d
       INNER JOIN LiveRows l ON l.ID = (d.ID % l.Rows)
UNION ALL
SELECT l.AutoID
     , ID = l.Rows + (d.ID + 1) * 2 - 1
FROM   DeadRows d
       INNER JOIN LiveRows l ON l.ID = (d.ID % l.Rows)
), Total As (
Select p.AutoID, p.GroupId, p.ProfileID, p.ProfileName, p.ID
From   LiveRows p
UNION ALL
Select p.AutoID, p.GroupId, p.ProfileID, p.ProfileName, o.ID
From   Ordered o
       INNER JOIN Profile p ON o.AutoID = p.AutoID
)
Select AutoID, GroupId, ProfileID, ProfileName
FROM   Total
ORDER BY ID
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d9ae0/21)

Will get it. It's not easy and the two `CTE` LiveRows ans DeadRows are used to add readability.
LiveRows and DeadRows filter [Profile] on the isLive field of [Group] (really a bad choice for a table name), adding the rownumber and, for the live data the rows count.
The rows count is used in Ordered two join the two subqueries and create the missing rows needed to have the same number of rows on both.
In the Ordered `CTE` is also calculated the position ID that will be used for the resultset, as that will start with the live data the number of live rows is added, the other part of the formula is a odd/even pair.
The Total `CTE` is to have a global ordering field available

I'm not sure where the last two rows in the question came from.

Comment: Hats Off to you man, query works perfectly, yes you are right, the last two rows shouldn't be in result set, I will remove it, also my real table name is not Group, I have modified my table and fields names on the question here :)

Answer (score 0):

The basic query for alternating the values is:

```
with lnl as (
      select AutoId, GroupId, ProfileId, ProfileName,
             row_number() over (partition by islive order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from profiles p join
           groups g
           on p.groupid = g.groupid
     )
select AutoId, GroupId, ProfileId, ProfileName
from lnl
order by seqnum, islive;
```

However, this will not replicate any of the values, so the last rows will be all of the same type.

My inclination would be to *reduce* the number of rows to valid pairs:

```
with lnl as (
      select AutoId, GroupId, ProfileId, ProfileName,
             row_number() over (partition by islive order by (select NULL)) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by islive) as cnt
      from profiles p join
           groups g
           on p.groupid = g.groupid
     ),
     cnts as (
      select min(case when islive = 0 then cnt end) as livecnt,
             min(case when islive = 1 then cnt end) as notlivecnt
      from lnl
     )
select AutoId, GroupId, ProfileId, ProfileName
from lnl join
     cnts
     on lnl.seqnum <= livecnt and lnl.seqnum <= notlivecnt
order by seqnum, islive;
```

Replicating is much harder.  One of the problems is that one of the groups may not have any rows, and that possibility complicates the logic.

Comment: No Gordon, that is never going to happen, my both IsLive = 0 and 1 both will always have data, and also IsLive = 1 will always have less data that 0

Comment: @HiteshSalian . . . *You* may know that, the logic in SQL doesn't necessarily know that.  Do you know the relative numbers in the two tables?

Comment: No. You are right, sql doesnt knows that, but still the requirement I have is to repeat the data alternatively. I tried your above query and it does alternate but once the IsLive = 1 records are over, the result set stops there